# Compare values within a column per partition

Tags: sql, teradata

I'm looking to compare values within a column per partition and see if they match but I'm not sure how to go about it.

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 22 | 900 | 0 |
| 24 | 900 | 0 |
| 22 | 006 | 1 |
| 24 | 006 | 1 |

Basically I want to check if the values for column **A** match the values for column **A** per partition of **C**.
So in this case the values for column **A** in the first partition of **C** (value 0) are `22 and 24`

the values for column **A** in the second partition of **C** (value 1) are also `22 and 24`. in this case there is a match. Is there a way to complete this comparison (and possibly put it in a new column with 1=match and 0=no match?

Comment: Are there always 2 rows per C partition

Comment: @Stu 3 at most.

Answer (score 0):

So trying to Help, I tried this on Postgres.
I think you'll find a way to adapt this sql to terrada's.

```
-- Lets create a table of your data (and more)
create table mydata (a integer, b integer, c integer);
            insert into mydata (a, b, c) values (22, 900, 0);
            insert into mydata (a, b, c) values (24, 900, 0);
            insert into mydata (a, b, c) values (22, 900, 1);
            insert into mydata (a, b, c) values (24, 900, 1);
            insert into mydata (a, b, c) values (22, 900, 2);
            insert into mydata (a, b, c) values (22, 900, 3);
            insert into mydata (a, b, c) values (21, 900, 2);
    
    -- Here below the solution
    SELECT  c,  
            CASE 
               when COUNT(c) OVER(PARTITION BY conc)  = 1 Then 0
               when COUNT(c) OVER(PARTITION BY conc)  > 1 Then 1
            END as flag
    FROM  
        ( SELECT c, STRING_AGG (a::text, ',') conc 
        FROM mydata
        GROUP BY  c ) sub1
```

I guess now you have idea how to do ;)